# What does "Prefetch views unpack data" in APDQC module do?

Tags: caching, performance

There is an option in the APDQC (Asynchronous Prefetch Database Query Cache)  https://www.drupal.org/project/apdqc module for:

**Prefetch views unpack data**

It's unclear what this does. Should this be turned on or left off as default?

Comment: The Views plugin classes have an `unpack_options` method which takes the options for the View/display in the database and applies them on top of the defaults. I don't know the Views code deeply enough for this to be anything other than a guess, but that option probably just allows that data to be cached by APDQC

Answer (score 1):

Really depends on your workload. In some cases having all of the views data prefetched is faster, in other cases it's slower. If you have 50+ views then it's best to leave it off, if you have just a couple views, turning it on is faster.

Side note: I created the patch for creating this cache in views, now I wish it was prefixed by the view name so prefetch would be easier.